# jqGrid setCell not working - need a image file to be shown if the col value is greater than 1

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to show a "!" mark whenever the priority column value is greater than 1. I was able to traverse the jqGrid rows and check for the column values however the jqGrid setCell is not working in my case. I am not sure where I am going

```
 var rowdata;
 var gridObj =  jQuery("#grid").getDataIDs();
 for(var i =0;i<gridObj.length;i++)
    {    
            rowdata = jQuery("#grid").getRowData(gridObj[i]);
            var val = $('#grid').jqGrid('getCell',gridObj[i],'Priority');
            //alert(val); //Displays priority value
            if(val > 1)
                    $("#grid").jqGrid('setCell',gridObj[i],'Priority', '', 'MyCell'); 

    }

  //jQuery("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");  **DOESNT WORK
```

css code has : **INCLUDED CSS CODE BECAUSE I DONT WANT A PLAIN TEXT (!) change I actually want a image file to be rendered in the column when the value is greater than 1**

```
.MyCell {
  color:'red';
  weightfont:'bold'
}
```

Table looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by doing this:

```
colModel :[ 
    {name:'Priority', index:'Priority', width:7, search:false, formatter: imageFormatter}, 
    function imageFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject){     
        if(cellvalue>1)
            return ("<center><img src='images/LuImportance.gif' /></center>");
        else
            return ("");
    }
]
```